# Perfect solution to validate a password

Tags: javascript, regex

I took an online JavaScript test where the 3rd problem was as follows:

Complete the checkPassword function, which should check if the password parameter adheres to the following rules:

- Must be longer than 6 characters.
- Allowed characters are lower or uppercase Latin alphabetic characters (a-z), numbers (0-9), and special characters +, $, #, \, / only.
- Must not have 3 or more consecutive numbers (e.g. "pass12p" is fine,
  but "pass125p" is not, because it contains "125")

>

My solution was as follows:

```js
function checkPassword(password) {
  return /^[a-zA-Z0-9\+\$\\\/#]{6,}$/.test(password) && !/[0-9]{3,}/.test(password);
}
```

This solution gave me the correct outputs for the given inputs.

But the ultimate test result told that the solution is just 75% correct sadly.

I think the perfect answer is expected to be a solution just with a single regular expression. Is there anyone who can give me a single regular expression that gives the same result? I am not so good at regular expression so please advise.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do search the site before asking a question - this exact one has been already answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at the start.

```
^(?!.*?\d{3})[a-zA-Z0-9\+\$\\\/#]{6,}$
```

`(?!.*?\d{3})` at the start asserts that the match won't contain atleast three consecutive digits. Then the regex engine tries to match the pattern `[a-zA-Z0-9\+\$\\\/#]` against the input string 6 or more times only if this condition is satisfied.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yQ8lT6/1)

Comment: The full lookahead syntax is: x(?!y) - where you mean x can be an empty value?

Comment: Because you're new to StackOverflow, i suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: The full lookahead syntax is: x(?!y) - where you mean x can be an empty value?

Comment: `x(?!y)` matches all the `x` which isn't followed by a character `y` . Likewise `^(?!.*?\d{3})` checks for the whole line where min 3 consecutive digits present or not. And this `(?!.*?\d{3})` assertion won't match even a single character. It's just an assertion whether the match is possible or not.

Comment: How do I mark your answer accepted?

Comment: ^(?!.*?\d{3}) is considered to have an empty x value, isn't it?

Comment: yep, right. Just click the tick mark present below to the down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]{6,}$
```

For consecutive number check

```
    public boolean isValid(final String userName,final String password) { 
    for(int i=0;(i+2)<userName.length();i++) if(password.indexof(userName.substring(i,i+2))!=-1) return false; return true; 
}
```

Comment: Java : Javascript = Ham : Hamster